# Написание и залив сигнального сервера python на хостинг

Tags: python, p2p, messenger, websokets

Я пытаюсь сделать Р2Р мессенджер на python, для этого написал кусок кода, который отвечает за поиск ip и port для соединения между двумя клиентами. Я не уверен, что этот код работает как надо, но для того, чтобы узнать это, мне нужно залить скрипт на сервер, и смотреть, что работает не так (С установкой и настройкой VirtualBox под разные ip возникли трудности, да и все равно в конечном итоге придется это делать).
  И теперь я окончательно потерялся, ведь, на сколько я понял, просто так залить скрипт на хостинг и обращаться к нему по айпи и порту не получится. И я не понимаю, тут нужно прикручивать какой нибудь фреймворк, или же по другому обращаться к хостингу ? Помогите пожалуйста со всем этим разобраться !

**CLIENT CODE**

```
import socket

ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.getfqdn())
port = 9090

input_command = input()
if input_command == "connect":
    print("ID = ")
    searching_id = input()
    message_to_Sserver = ip, ",", port, ",", searching_id

    sock = socket.socket()
    sock.connect(('198.2255.5225.548', 9090))
    print("connected to server")
    sock.send(message_to_Sserver.encode("utf-8"))
    print("request send")
    data = sock.recv()
    sock.close()

    udata = data.decode("utf-8")
    udata = udata.split(",")
    ip_Client2 = udata[i][0]
    port_Client2 = udata[i][1]
    print("conneting to client2")
    socket.connect((ip_Client2, port_Client2))
    print("connection done")
else:
    socket.bind('',9090)
    socket.listen()
```

**SERVER CODE**

```
import socket

socket = socket.socket()
ALL_ID = [["192.32.32.32", 9090, 1111], ["192.32.32.89", 9030, 2222]]

socket.bind(('', 9090))
print(socket.gethostbyname(socket.getfqdn()))
print("listening to client")
socket.listen()
conn, addr = socket.accept()
print("connected")

while True:
data = conn.recv(1024)
if not data:
    break
print("request received")

udata = data.decode("utf-8")
message_from_Client = udata.split(",")
ip_Client_wchS1 = message_from_Client[0]
port_Client_wchS1 = message_from_Client[1]
searching_id_Client = message_from_Client[2]
i = 0
while True:
    i += 1
    if searching_id_Client == ALL_ID[i][2]:
        ip_Client_w0hS2 = ALL_ID[i][0]
        port_Client_w0hS2 = ALL_ID[i][1]
        searched_id_Client = ALL_ID[i][2]
        message_to_Client_wchS1 = ip_Client_w0hS2, ",", port_Client_w0hS2
        message_to_Client_whoS2 = ip_Client, ",", port_Client_wchS1
        break
conn.close()
print("connection closed")

socket.sendto(message_to_Client_wchS1.encode("utf-8"), ip_Client_wchS1)
print("reply to C1")
socket.sendto(message_to_Client_whoS2.encode("utf-8"), ip_Client_w0hS2)
print("reply to C2")

socket.bind(('', 9090))
socket.listen()
```

Comment: у вас сервер слушает 9090 порт, запустите у себя и пробуйте подключиться, в чем проблема?

Comment: в том, что тогда и у сервера, и у клиента будет одинаковый ip

Comment: Ну, сервер будет отдавать клиентам такой же ip с, например, разными портами. Не обязательно заливать куда-то чтобы проверить

Answer (score 0):

Заведи самую дешёвую виртуальную машину у какого нибудь VPS хостера.
Например: vscale.io (промокод radio-t)
digitalocean.com (промокод radio_t)
И много других. И тестируй себе наздоровье. 250-500 рублей в месяц думаю наскребешь.